# Implicit Function Theorem, local form

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am currently trying to understand the proof of the implicit function theorem in the local case, i.e. where $F(x,y)=0$.

Consider $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ and let $(x_0,y_0)=(0,1)$ so that $F(x_0,y_0)=0$ and choose some neighborhood $D$ around $(0,1)$

In this case we have, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)=2$.

The proof I am reading says to choose some $N \subset D$ such that $N=I \times J$ where $(0,1)$ is the center of this rectangle and $J=[c,d]$

This is the part I am not understanding: Since $F_2 > 0$ on $N$ the function $F(x_0, \cdot)$ is increasing on $J$. How? What does $F(x_0,\cdot)$ even represent?

Moreover, does  $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)=2$  imply that $F(x,y)$ is increasing at $(0,1)$ in the $y$-direction? If so, I do not see how this is possible from the graph of the unit circle.

Comment: $F(x_0, y_0) = F(0, 1) = 0^2+1^2 = 1$. Did you mean $F(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$?

Comment: I meant $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$. Just edited.

Comment: $F(x_0, \cdot)$ is a function $y \mapsto F(x_0, y) = x_0^2+y^2-1 = y^2-1$ which is increasing for $y > 0$.